# Error After Updating the Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio

I have updated my Android Studio version 3.0.1 but now created a small project but it shows me a lot of errors. How can I fix these?

Error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `google()` repository to your project (root) `build.gradle`. Something like this:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
  }
}
```

Then uncheck `Offline work` option from `File -> Setting -> Gradle` in Global Gradle settings (this maybe different in your OS. I'm using Linux).

Answer (score 0):

In the top there is a gradle sync error pop-up.Click on the 'Try Again' or 'sync Now'option.

If still not resolved, go to build option and rebuild project.